# Default font of AttributeString

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

What's the default font of Attribute String? I am tying to make part of the string as bold using

```
[attrStr setFont:[UIFont ...] range:[attrStr.string rangeOfString:@"substring"]];
```

where can I control the rest of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [class reference for `NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Note that the default font for `NSAttributedString` objects is Helvetica 12-point